# How to disable\change WebRTC IP leak on android?

Tags: android, proxy, webrtc

When I use proxy in android emulator I change IP but I still have a leak via WebRTC.
I need to block WebRTC at all or somehow connect to proxy ip.

I tried block webrtc in browser but application still get my real ip.
Tried to block it with iptables but it didn't work.
Is there any option to prevent ip leaking via webrtc?